# websocket connection closes upon writing to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, writefile

so i am connecting a client to a server using websockets (ws). i successfully send msgs to the server and send it back to the client.Problem is when I try to write the received message to a file the server disconnects the client. The message is successfully written but i end up disconnecting client. Looks like something about the write functions disconnect my client. I am using fs.writFile(), I already tried fs.createWriteStream(). Reading the file however does not disconnect it.

```
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const fs = require('fs');

let counts = [0,0]
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    console.log(' Received request for ' + request.url);
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection',(ws)=>{
    console.log("serving...")

    ws.on('message',(message)=>{
        console.log("Received:"+message)

        if(message ==='1'){
            counts[0]=parseInt(counts[0])+1
            fs.writeFile('votecnts.txt',`${counts[0].toString()} ${counts[1].toString()}`,(err) =>{
                if(err) throw err
            })
        }
        else if (message==='2'){
            counts[1]=parseInt(counts[1])+1
            fs.writeFile('votecnts.txt',`${counts[0].toString()} ${counts[1].toString()}`,(err) =>{
                if(err) throw err
            })
        }
        else{console.log(typeof(message))}

        ws.send("cand_one: "+counts[0].toString()+"\n cand_two: "+counts[1].toString())    
    })



    ws.on('close',function(){
        console.log("lost client")
    })
})
```

Comment: Are you getting an error on either of your `fs.writeFile()` operations?  Are you running any sort of development tool that automatically restarts your server when files change?

Comment: No I get no error. It actually executes successfully writing to the file. No error is caught in the err callback function

Comment: Please answer the second part of my previous question.  For example, are you using nodemon?  If so, it may cause your server to be restarted automatically everytime your server writes to the file.   And, causing your server to restart would kill the webSocket connection.

Comment: Oh no. I was not using nodemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I was running both server and client on localhost while developing. And therefore the file directories are the same. I later found out that it is impossible to write to file in javascript at the client side because of security reasons. So all I did was to change the url of the server to a remote machine and I was able to write to file using server code. specifically with the writeFile() function in the code above. I actually did not have to touch my code. It was just about configuration and set up.

Comment: If you logged what error you got, you probably would have figured this out a lot quicker.  `if (err) throw err` in an asynchronous callback should never, ever be written that way.  Write proper error handling and log all errors and life will be easier.